# How to make if statement with color code

Tags: java, android, colors, pixel

I got a little problem, what I think, can't be hard.
but somehow, I miss that "can't be hard" part :).

I got a code, that reads the colors of an image:

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.four_colors);


    //define the array size
    rgbValues = new int[bmp.getWidth()][bmp.getHeight()]; 

    //Print in LogCat's console each of one the RGB and alpha values from the 4 corners of the image
    //Top Left
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++){
    Log.i("Pixel Value", "pixel x="+j +k + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(j, k)));
    test = Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(j,  k));


        }
    }

    //get the ARGB value from each pixel of the image and store it into the array
    for(int i=0; i < bmp.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < bmp.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            //This is a great opportunity to filter the ARGB values
            rgbValues[i][j] = bmp.getPixel(i, j);               
        }   
    }

    System.out.println(PixelNumber);
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

This code works like a charm.
But I tried to implement an if statement like:

```
if (color == black){
    number++;
}
```

So every pixels he sees that is black, he must increase the number with 1.

Tried almost everything I could came up to make a good if statement around this code, but nothing seems to work.
So what is the correct place and if statement to make in this code?

And maybe if you got more time (do not put too much effort in this if you don't want) is it possible to check on a color-range instead of 1 color only, So it picks all green colors. (same as Color range in photoshop).

Comment: From the description its not possible to understand WHERE you've tried the if statement, there is no mention of a variable color anywhere in your other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getPixel returns the 4bytes of ARGB in an integer. What you should do is to compose the color you want to count (the [argb](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method of [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) will help you) and test on this value with `getPixel(x, y)`.
For black this will be easy:

```
if(Color.BLACK == bmp.getPixel(x, y))
     //doit
```

For ranges you can use the `green`/`red`/`blue` methods, each returning the value of that component. If it is non-zero, the pixel has color from that component.

Comment: You compare an `int` to a `Color`. This should give a compile time error.

Comment: Color.BLACK is an int constant. Look at the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#BLACK

Comment: @Andreas_D `Color.BLACK` and `getPixel()` are both ints

Comment: Thanks, if I look at the if statement now I can give myself a facepalm.
I really aprriciate what you did!

Comment: Ah, wrong context ;) `java.awt.Color.BLACK` is a instance of `Color` while `android.graphics.Color.BLACK` is an `int` ;) And we're talking android here.

Comment: But - be advised, that this method only counts 'black' pixels with an opacity set to zero. It will definitly fail, if the picture is transparent.

Comment: That's true. If the alpha channel is in use you have to either do the masking as you proposed or get the rgb with a built-in method and use that as the basis of comparison.

Comment: Thanks for all help.
Just this for color range check (for now):
for (int i = 50; i < 254; i++){
      if (Color.rgb(0, i, 0) == bmp.getPixel(j, k)){ }

Answer (score 0):

you can to that with the condition like  if(rgbValues[i][j] == Color.BLACK).

that code will be like the following.

```
 //get the ARGB value from each pixel of the image and store it into the array
    for(int i=0; i < bmp.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < bmp.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            //This is a great opportunity to filter the ARGB values

            rgbValues[i][j] = bmp.getPixel(i, j);   
            if(rgbValues[i][j] == Color.BLACK) {

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap#getPixel(int, int)` returns an `int` value that represents transparency (alpha) and color (rgb) of a given pixel.

The RGB value of black is `(0x00, 0x00, 0x00)`. So if you want to test for black *and* ignore the alpha value, the test should go like this:

```
if ((rgbValue[i][j] & 0x00ffffff) == 0) {
   // this pixel is black
   number++;
}
```

*Color range* is very difficult. First we need computable definition of *green* (for instance). *green* is pretty subjective. Once you have an algorithm at hand, put it in a different method and do a call like this:

```
if (isGreenish(rgbValue[i][j])) {     // magic method
   // this pixel is some sort of green
   number++;
}
```